# Disable only one collider when two colliders are touching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity 2D and was wondering if there was any way to do what I need.

Please check the image of Two items with hitting colliders.

[image: Two items with hitting colliders]

When the player is activating both colliders and then the pick up button is pressed, the player equips both items. I want to disable one of the item's colliders when another item is nearby and then re-enable it when its by itself again. How should I go about doing this? I was thinking using a list but since both weapons use the same scripts (they're prefabs) I think that would create two lists that would serve no purpose and probably crash.

My initial check was to see if another item was nearby, and if so disable its collider, but it did that for both the items rendering both useless.

Comment: This entire problem seems to be caused by the logic for picking up an item being within the item itself. Why not put this logic somewhere else? Perhaps in the prefab of the player? Then just have a method in the item class you can call when it gets picked up if you need to do some logic there.

Comment: @Jesse Yeah you're right. I haven't solved it yet but you gave me some ideas so I'm gonna spend a while putting the equip logic on the player and hopefully fix my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Boolean flag in the player code
something like :

```
if(hasWeapon == false)
{
  //put pick up code here
}
```

so that if a weapon is selected, it will not be entered into the pick-up code until you drop the weapon.